# How to detect front-channel logout in a second existing, open browser window and redirect the user to a logged-out page?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

Say I have two applications open, one in each tab, and they both leverage the same SSO server. The user globally logs out (front-channel) in App A, but App B remains open in another tab. The front-channel takes care of wiping the cookies but ideally there would be a way to redirect App B to a "you've been logged out" page. However, since it's not possible to detect HTTPOnly cookies via javascript, how can the javascript running in App B's tab detect the removal of the cookie and direct the user? I suppose we could write a non-HTTPOnly cookie as well and monitor that but I thought there may be a better solution out there.

Comment: Federated Sign Out is the concept you are looking for here probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdentityServer4 supports this via the "session status change" spec here:

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#ChangeNotification

This allows your app to ping (via postMessage calls to an iframe) for changes to the current session and receive a response indicating if it's changed or not. This all happens client-side and it uses a non-HTTP-only cookie which is populated with the current session ID.

The endpoint in question is advertised as `check_session_iframe` in the `/.well-known/openid-configuration`

oidc-client-js implements this out of the box but for a server-side app you may have to roll your own.